# How to customize the visible area of the scroll viewer's content

Tags: wpf, scroll, scrollviewer

The `ScrollViewer`'s default behavior is, that the content stops on the bottom of the `ScrollViewer`'s view port:

[image]

I would like to change the behavior, so that the content can be scrolled to the top of the scroll `ScrollViewer`'s view port:

[image]

a) Is it possible to configure the existing scroll viewer that way?

b) If not, what is the best way to achieve that behavior?

Comment: You mean, Initially `content` on the bottom of `viewport` will be shown at the top and the `content` and will move upwards on scrolling down the `scrollviewer`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @Gopichandar: Yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the scrollable content in a `Grid` with 3 rows. The scrollable content occupies the second row. The other two have the same `Height` of the `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="50">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <YourScrollableContent Grid.Row="1"/>
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I've no way to test it in order to see if this code is *perfect*, but I'm sure this can be a way :)

Maybe you can bind the `Height` of the 2 rows with the `Height` of the `ScrollViewer`:

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=Height,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}"/>
```

Comment: I used the following binding to support resizing: `<RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}"/>`